# Change CSS in Magento 2.0 Theme

Tags: css, less, magento2, magento-2.0

I use Magento Blank as a parent theme.

I have created `_theme.less.css` in `/app/design/frontend/MYVENDORNAME/MYTHEMENAME/web/css/source/` that contains this code:

```
@button-primary__background: @color-orange-red1;
@button-primary__hover__background: @color-orange-red4;
@button-primary__border: 1px solid @color-orange-red2;
@button-primary__hover__border: 1px solid @color-orange-red2;
```

I have flushed cache.

But buttons are still blue.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Start with http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-preprocess.html.

Answer (score 1):

This code needs to go into a .less file and be compiled into a .css file as this isn't code styles that can be read natively in a css file.

Answer (score 0):

First add your custom css

Go to:

```
/app/design/frontend/Magento/MYVENDORNAME/MYTHEMENAME/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

And add css under head block looks like this:

```
<head><css src="css/custom.css" /></head>
```

And than after create custom.css file in this path:

```
/app/design/frontend/Magento/MYVENDORNAME/MYTHEMENAME/web/css/custom.css
```

Run your css, hopefully it's work for you.

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do was to copy files from:

```
/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/
```

Into theme directory:

```
/app/design/frontend/MYVENDORNAME/MYTHEMENAME/web/css/
```

You don't have to move all files, you can just replace the files you want to make changes to.

I think you have to learn LESS to be able to style the theme properly. But for simple **static** CSS changes this might work:

1) Add `/dev1/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web/css/_styles.less` with the following content:

```
@import 'source/lib/_lib.less'; // Global lib
@import 'source/_sources.less'; // Theme styles
@import 'source/_components.less'; // Components styles (modal/sliding panel)

body{background:#f00}
```